# Using the OS library for volumes and external locations (abfss) in databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, operating-system, databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I have several processes in Databricks using the OS library, for creating txt files, checking directories, etc.

With the arrival of Volumes and the use of external locations "abfss", mount points will be more exposed as something legacy.

In this case, what are the best practices for using the OS library for simple operations like these?

In some tests, it was not possible to verify the existence of files or folders, or even their creation for both cases, volumes and abfss.

Could someone help me?

I tried to create something simple but the directories weren't recognized

Answer (score 1):

The main goal of Unity Catalog Volumes is to provide unified access to arbitrary files using both Spark & local file APIs.

For example, the file on the Volume will be accessible via normal OS APIs, like this:

```py
import os

file_name = "/Volumes/main/default/test/test.txt"
os.path.exists(file_name)
with open(file_name, "r") as f:
  for l in f:
    print(l)
```

and with Spark APIs:

```py
file_name = "/Volumes/main/default/test/test.txt"
df = spark.read.text(file_name)
display(df)
```

Directory operations on Volumes work as well:

```py
os.makedirs("/Volumes/main/default/test/tmp")
os.path.exists("/Volumes/main/default/test/tmp") # -> True
```

Comment: I will try more tests. Is it possible the same operations for abfss://container@storage.dfs.core.windows.net/ also?

Comment: No. Because local APIs don’t know about that storage type - for volumes there is a fuse implementation